# React app does not render when I bind this more than once in constructor

Tags: reactjs

In a simple `React` application using `ES6` I have a `counter` that updates the value of the `integer` set initially to `0` when a `button` is clicked. When I `bind(this)` to the `function` to `addOne()` the app works fine. But when I bind(this) to all three buttons in the constructor the app does not load due to this error,

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   '__reactInternalInstance$ggcqbwtkkb' of null

I have read that if I bind in the render method it will create the function every time the page renders. I want to avoid that.

**Question**

Why when I `bind(this)` to one `onClick` `method` in the `constructor` the app loads fine and the one button can be `clicked`, but when I `bind(this)` to the other two `buttons` the app throws the previously mentioned error?

**Constructor works when it is like this,**

```
constructor(props) {
            super(props);
                this.state = {
                    count: 0
            }
            this.addOne = this.addOne.bind(this);
        }
```

**But when I add the other two binds, it does not work,**

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
            this.state = {
                count: 0
        }
        this.addOne = this.addOne.bind(this);
        this.addTwo = this.addTwo.bind(this);
        this.addTen = this.addTen.bind(this);
    }
```

**Code Example**

```
class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
            this.state = {
                count: 0
        }
        this.addOne = this.addOne.bind(this);
        this.addTwo = this.addTwo.bind(this);
        this.addTen = this.addTen.bind(this);
    }
    addOne() {
        this.setState({
            count: this.state.count + 1
        })
    }
    addFive() {
        this.setState({
            count: this.state.count + 5
        })
    }
    addTen() {
        this.setState({
            count: this.state.count + 10
        })
    }
    render() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
            <div className="home-intro">
                <h2>Welcome to Home Component</h2>
            </div>
            <div className="counter">
                <h3>Count: {this.state.count}</h3>
            </div>
            <div className="btn-group">
                <button onClick={this.addOne} className="btn blue-btn">Add 1</button>
                <button onClick={this.addFive} className="btn green-btn">Add 5</button>
                <button onClick={this.addTen} className="btn red-btn">Add 10</button>
            </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
}
```

**Visual Example**

[image]

Comment: Um.. because there is no `addTwo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a typo

```
addTwo()
```

Does not exists you only have `addFive(), addTen() and addOne()`

See below the fixed code you provided

```js
class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
            this.state = {
                count: 0
        }
        this.addOne = this.addOne.bind(this);
        this.addFive = this.addFive.bind(this);
        this.addTen = this.addTen.bind(this);
    }
    addOne() {
        this.setState({
            count: this.state.count + 1
        })
    }
    addFive() {
        this.setState({
            count: this.state.count + 5
        })
    }
    addTen() {
        this.setState({
            count: this.state.count + 10
        })
    }
    render() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
            <div className="home-intro">
                <h2>Welcome to Home Component</h2>
            </div>
            <div className="counter">
                <h3>Count: {this.state.count}</h3>
            </div>
            <div className="btn-group">
                <button onClick={this.addOne} className="btn blue-btn">Add 1</button>
                <button onClick={this.addFive} className="btn green-btn">Add 5</button>
                <button onClick={this.addTen} className="btn red-btn">Add 10</button>
            </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Home />, document.querySelector('#app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hahaha indeed ! :P